# I'm trying to make a responsive SVG, but it isn't showing on Safari

Tags: html, svg, safari, responsive-design

I have an SVG that I want to be responsive. I haven't set a `width` and `height` attribute because I ideally want it to be automatic. However, Safari doesn't render the SVG correctly without them.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 191 6" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet">
 <path d="M0.113249 3L3 5.88675L5.88675 3L3 0.113249L0.113249 3ZM3 3.5H190.5V2.5H3V3.5Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_prev_<?php echo $i; ?>)" />
  <defs>
   <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_prev_<?php echo $i; ?>" x1="3" 
    y1="3" x2="190.5" y2="3" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"> <stop stop-color="white" />
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
   </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Setting them to `auto` doesn't work either. How can I make the SVG appear and scale properly in Safari while maintaining responsiveness?

Comment: Can't reproduce this error. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/GRLvpjm)

Comment: in my case, your current code works perfectly, both Safari and Chrome are typically the same, what is your OS and your Safari version?

Comment: https://stage.avantto.com.br/epic-e1000-gx/#epic_trechos

Here is the page. It works in Chrome but not in Safari.

Comment: the svg alone (without the atributes) doesn't work on Safari, so I had to put it inside a div and some css, had to make it more easy. Thanks for the answers, case closed.